# (Swift) Location permissions toggle not showing up in settings

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-location

I am working on a `Swift` app that uses location permissions and I am encountering an interesting problem.  If `Location Services` are disabled for the device, and you open the app for the first time the authorization alert view says you must go to settings and enable this.  If you go to settings and then enable location services and then go to the apps section in Settings, the Location toggle section is not there, only the Siri & Search section is displayed (see the picture for what I am talking about).

The only way to make that section appear is to kill the app completely and re-open it.  Is there anyway I can have that section appear at all times?  I am using a `Settings.bundle` with nothing in the root and I am asking for `WhenInUse` permissions.

[image]